# How to visualize the contents of any file as an image?

Tags: image, file, binary

I would like to print (in a paper) the contents of any file, so that someone can recreate the original file from the scanned image.

Think of it as storing a file in paper.

One solution is to make a 2D barcode by printing the binary components of the file (1 as black squares, 0 as white squares).

I don't want to reinvent the wheel. If there is any (open) standard to make this, I would be grateful to hear it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you get the content of the file and then do a base64 encode on it. Then, the resulting code can be used to print the contents of the file on paper. Finally you can scan the paper, do some OCR on the scanned image, reverse the base64 encoding and you will end up with the binary form of the file.

Answer (score 1):

I'd look into [QR Codes.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code)  Unfortunately, they max out at about 3 kilobytes each, but you could simply print a page with many of them, in order of how your file is appended.  I'd imagine that you could fit maybe 20 kilobytes on a page if you had a good printer and scanner.  I'd also suggest compressing the data first to save space.

Comment: Good answer, but "adding some kind of error checking" is probably unnecessary, as QR codes already include significant levels of redundancy. Depending on what level of error correction you provide, QR codes permit up to 30% of their data to be destroyed/misread without issue.

Comment: I did not know that about QR codes.  That's pretty awesome.  Edited.